# Show 1 image and 2 partial image in caroufredsel

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

Is it possible to show 1 single image and 2 other partial images using caroufredsel like this

[image]

If not could you please tell so.

Comment: yes, perfectly possible. please show your code and a jsfiddle

Comment: @atmd its actually bundled with a word press theme, so i need to make modification within the theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes caroufredsel is very universal.

You will best check these cool examples: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/2/

You can find a lot of inspiration there.

BTW kudos for using caroufredsel, I find it the best carousel out there